# Transparency problem with the terminal!

Tags: 12.04, command-line

Transparency sliding bar is at full (Option Available in profile preferences).
Even then terminal has solid color. It was working well a day before.

How to roll back?

Comment: At full? Sliding the bar to the Max, it applies maximum opacity, so you will end up with a solid color. For full transparency, slide the bar do the left, setting it to Minimum, so you will have a transparent Terminal.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question :(  got lil confused and thought there went something with the terminal :(

Comment: Don't need to sorry, we are all here to learn and anyone needs to be born knowing everything ;) I'll make my comment an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the usage of the transparency sliding bar:

Sliding the bar to the Max, it applies maximum opacity, so you will end up with a solid color.

For transparent colors, slide the bar do the left, close to the Minimum, so you will have a transparent Terminal.

Comment: still not working well,terminal is transparent but not serving the purpose in a sense that it is always showing the desktop even when the background is some webpage or directory

Comment: It may be occurring if you are using Unity 2D or if your graphic card doesn't support real transparency. Maybe you can try something with CCSM, you can install it with this command: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Comment: Still not working...I had installed nvidia 610m drivers..since then it is not working...

Comment: Did you activated Composite, OpenGL and Window Decoration in CCSM? If not try it out, but if it doesn't work it means that your graphic card doesn't support real time transparency.

Comment: where to apply those procedure??? Before installation it was doing well...

Comment: Just type in the Dash 'CCSM' and it will show you CompizConfig Tool, open it and from there you will be able to tinker around.